# Enforcing DateTime Kinds

Tags: c#, .net, datetime

We're writing a dll that can be accessed by other teams. **One of our requirements is that every DateTime passed has a DateTimeKind.Utc.**

However, we're not enforcing this requirement which leads to errors. So we were wondering **how we can enforce this**.

We had a few ideas:

- Write an aspect that checks each parameter passed to a method. Throw an exception when the Kind != UTC. This works but does not work when you pass an object that contains a DateTime.
- Change all our DateTimes with a custom object, UtcDateTime.

This might work but would need to make sure that we replace every DateTime and all calls to our datetimes. Would look something like this:

```
public class UtcDateTime
{
  private DateTime _dateTime;
  public UtcDateTime(DateTime dateTime)
  {
    if(dateTime.Kind != DateTimeKind.Utc)
    {
        throw new ArgumentException();
    }
    _dateTime = dateTime;
  }
}
```

Any better ways to do this?

Comment: If you want to trigger an error, I'd go with code contracts as suggested by @Daniel.  But I think a better approach would be to convert the DateTime to UTC (assuming that's possible), and log a stack trace -- like Daniel's alternative suggestion (or your aspect idea).

Answer (score 3):

> Change all our DateTimes with a custom object, UtcDateTime.

If you want to go that way and replace `DateTime` with something else, you might as well use `DateTimeOffset`, which includes time zone information.

Comment: Yes, and crucially for us, things like "operator >" converts both sides to UTC for the comparison - unlike DateTime which doesn't even check the kinds for you. The storage is a bit bloated (long+enum+int) if all you wanted was a strongly typed UTC-only ticks value, but at least it's safe.

Answer (score 1):

You could use code contracts to enforce this.

Read about them here.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264808(v=vs.110).aspx

As an example, you could use

```
Contract.Requires(yourDateTime.Kind == DateTime.Utc);
```

Alternatively, you could enforce the conversion in your method. If it is `DateTimeKind.Unspecified`, throw.

```
void Foo(ObjectWithDateTime foo)
{
    if (foo.Date.Kind == DateTimeKind.Unspecified) {
        throw ....
    }
    // convert here.
}
```